# How to show "regular price" instead of a "discounted price" on mini-cart (Woo)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I have read like every single topic about woocommerce but cannot find out how to show regular price instead of a discounted price on mini-cart. (Yes, i want to show regular price in mini-cart.php)

I think i should modify **mini-cart.php:*41*** but i dont know how i can show regular price.

```
$product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Can someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_regular_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i used this on **mini-cart.php:41** and worked!

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_regular_price', $_product->get_regular_price(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```