# How to get the product sale price on WooCommerce 'mini' cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display the product `sale price` instead of `price` on this cart "popup" [image]

The code responsible to get the `price`is shown below and I really feel this is where I need to change.
`$product_price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );`

Any lights on how to achieve it ?

I've found a similiar question here on StackOverflow but with no right answers -> [How to show "regular price" instead of a "discounted price" on mini-cart (Woo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184796/how-to-show-regular-price-instead-of-a-discounted-price-on-mini-cart-woo)

Thank you anyway !

Comment: I think it's a sync problem. The sale price is printed just when the page is loaded but, about one second later, it's updated to regular price when the page finishes loading

Answer (score 0):

```
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
    return $product->get_sale_price();
     }
    return $product->get_regular_price();
```

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but probably I shouldn't `return`the value because it is used on $product_price and `echoed` later on the code.
In fact, I tried some similar solutions and the page freezes, showing me no error ( I guess because WP_DEBUG is turned off than it just freezes)

Comment: No, it's not because WP_DEBUG is off, I just set debugging mode as explained here https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress and it stills showing me no error message or log file

Answer (score 0):

You may use **"get_price()"** for achieving the  sale price of any product, for example:

```
global $product;
$pro_price = $product->get_price();
```

the function **"get_price"** always return the sale price (if present, otherwise it will return regular price instead)